# Tableau Bar labels alignment

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-prep

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llB5n.png)
Please help, I do not have a label alignment option on my bar graph. Is there a solution to this problem?

I tried aligning the text inside the text box to the left or center but the labels did not move.

Comment: feel free to reach out to the community : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click on the measure used in the bar chart, then you have the alignment options, under Pane, you can format the alignment, like this:

[image]

Comment: if this helps, mark my answer as "Solved"